# Collinear features and their effect on linear models,Task: 1 Logistic Regression

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
%matplotlib inline
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`enter code here`
data = pd.read_csv('task_d.csv')
data.head()
```

**output**

```
         x         y           z          x*x      2*y           2*z+3*x*x     w        target
0   -0.581066   0.841837    -1.012978   -0.604025   0.841837    -0.665927   -0.536277   0
1   -0.894309   -0.207835   -1.012978   -0.883052   -0.207835   -0.917054   -0.522364   0
2   -1.207552   0.212034    -1.082312   -1.150918   0.212034    -1.166507   0.205738    0
3   -1.364174   0.002099    -0.943643   -1.280666   0.002099    -1.266540   -0.665720   0
4   -0.737687   1.051772    -1.012978   -0.744934   1.051772    -0.792746   -0.735054   0
X = data.drop(['target'], axis=1).values
Y = data['target'].values
```

**Doing perturbation test to check the presence of collinearity**
**Task: 1 Logistic Regression¶**

```
data.corr()['target']
```

**output**

```
x            0.728290
y           -0.690684
z            0.969990
x*x          0.719570
2*y         -0.690684
2*z+3*x*x    0.764729
w            0.641750
target       1.000000
Name: target, dtype: float64

corr = X.corr()
ax = sns.heatmap(corr,vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0,cmap=sns.diverging_palette(20, 220, n=200),square=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=45,horizontalalignment='right');
```

**output**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-749cdea8ad1a> in <module>
      1 ##correlation matrix using seaborn heatmap##https://towardsdatascience.com/better-heatmapscorr = X.corr()
----> 2 corr = X.corr()
      3 ax = sns.heatmap(corr,vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0,cmap=sns.diverging_palette(20, 220, n=200),square=True)
      4 ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=45,horizontalalignment='right');

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'corr'
```

How  can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, was your question answered? If so, could you please accept and upvote the answer? If not, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 1):

Why did you use .values() when creating X? That returns a numpy array.

If you remove the .values(), your X will remain a pandas DataFrame, which has the .corr() method. Then your code will run as you intended.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If this helped you, could you please [accept and/or upvote it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of X call directly to the dataset

This will help:

```py
corr = data.corr()
ax = sns.heatmap(corr,vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0,cmap=sns.diverging_palette(20, 220, n=200),square=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=45,horizontalalignment='right')
```